# Add new line in Tooltip

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I have the following project : http://jsfiddle.net/3yhbyy2g/70/

I would like to know how to show tooltip with multiple lines rather than one line.

```
tooltip:{visible:true,template: "x : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.x)))#, y : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.y)))#, k : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.k)))# "}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting [html `<br>` breaks](http://www.quackit.com/html/tags/html_br_tag.cfm) in the template works as expected.

```
tooltip:{visible:true,template: "x : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.x)))#,<br> y : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.y)))#,<br> k : #=kendo.format('{0:n0}', (Math.abs(dataItem.k)))# "}
```